# Company Column on Sales Order/Invoice/CreditMemo/Shipment Grid

Tags: plugin, third-party-module, column, custom-column-grid, order-grid

I have built a module to show the Billing and Shipping Company Name in the Admin Grids for Order, Invoice, CreditMemo, and Shipment. I still can't believe this is not built into Magento2.

At first I was extending `Sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Grid/Collection` using `_renderFiltersBefore` and `joinLeft`, but I decided to convert it to a Plugin instead and try to use `aroundGetReport`.

Which both were working just fine, until I added a third-party module to handle our shipping costs. This third-party module is also joining tables to be added to the Sales Order Grid, which now it's conflicting with my module. I was able to get the `Sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Grid/Collection` using `_renderFiltersBefore` version to work with the ShipperHQ module.

But, I also added a third-party Gift Registry module which has it's own Sales Order Grid within the module to show placed orders for each gift registry. This is also conflicting because it is using `entity_id` from `sales_order_grid` as well.

However, now that I have moved to a Plugin, I cannot seem to get `_renderFiltersBefore` to work (display data). Plus I was unable to get the data to show on the Gift Registry grid with either solution.

Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'entity_id' in where clause is ambiguous

Below are the files which work correctly when I have the 2 third party modules disabled.

`di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

<!-- Add Company Name to Customer Grid -->
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Customer" type="Trucatch\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Customer" />

<!-- Add Company Name to Order Grids -->
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <plugin name="sales_order_additional_columns" type="Trucatch\Sales\Plugin\AddColumnsSalesOrderGridCollection" sortOrder="100" disabled="false" />
    <plugin name="sales_invoice_additional_columns" type="Trucatch\Sales\Plugin\AddColumnsSalesInvoiceGridCollection" sortOrder="100" disabled="false" />
    <plugin name="sales_shipment_additional_columns" type="Trucatch\Sales\Plugin\AddColumnsSalesShipmentGridCollection" sortOrder="100" disabled="false" />
    <plugin name="sales_creditmemo_additional_columns" type="Trucatch\Sales\Plugin\AddColumnsSalesCreditMemoGridCollection" sortOrder="100" disabled="false" />
    <plugin name="sales_view_invoice_additional_columns" type="Trucatch\Sales\Plugin\AddColumnsSalesViewInvoiceGridCollection" sortOrder="100" disabled="false" />
    <plugin name="sales_view_shipment_additional_columns" type="Trucatch\Sales\Plugin\AddColumnsSalesViewShipmentGridCollection" sortOrder="100" disabled="false" />
    <plugin name="sales_view_creditmemo_additional_columns" type="Trucatch\Sales\Plugin\AddColumnsSalesViewCreditMemoGridCollection" sortOrder="100" disabled="false" />
</type>

<!-- Adjust Order # Length -->
<type name="Magento\SalesSequence\Model\Sequence">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="pattern" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[%s%'.05d%s]]></argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

</config>
```

`AddColumnsSalesOrderGridCollection.php`

```
<?php namespace Trucatch\Sales\Plugin;

class AddColumnsSalesOrderGridCollection
{

private $resource;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
) {
    $this->resource = $resource;
}

public function aroundGetReport(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    $requestName
) {
    $result = $proceed($requestName);
    if ($requestName == 'sales_order_grid_data_source') {
        if ($result instanceof \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection) {
            $select = $result->getSelect();
            $select->joinLeft(
                ['soa1' => $this->resource->getTableName('sales_order_address')],
                'main_table.entity_id = soa1.parent_id AND soa1.address_type = "billing"',
                array('billing_company' => 'company')
            )
            ->distinct();
            $select->joinLeft(
                ['soa2' => $this->resource->getTableName('sales_order_address')],
                'main_table.entity_id = soa2.parent_id AND soa2.address_type = "shipping"',
                array('shipping_company' => 'company')
            )
            ->distinct();
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
}
```

`sales_order_grid.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">

<!-- "sales_order_grid_data_source" -->
<columns name="sales_order_columns">

    <!-- sales_order_address billing_company -->
    <column name="billing_company">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Bill-to Company</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">4</item>
                <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                <!-- <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item> -->
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

    <!-- sales_order_address shipping_company -->
    <column name="shipping_company">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Ship-to Company</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">6</item>
                <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                <!-- <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item> -->
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

</columns>

</listing>
```

Now the file from ShipperHQ that is causing the conflicts

`CollectionFactory.php`

```
<?php

namespace ShipperHQ\Shipper\Plugin\Order;

class CollectionFactory
{
/**
 * @var \ShipperHQ\Shipper\Helper\LogAssist
 */
private $shipperLogger;
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection */
private $resource;

public function __construct(
    \ShipperHQ\Shipper\Helper\LogAssist $shipperLogger,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
) {
    $this->shipperLogger = $shipperLogger;
    $this->resource = $resource;
}

public function aroundGetReport(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    $requestName
) {

    $result = $proceed($requestName);
    if ($requestName == 'sales_order_grid_data_source') {
        if ($result instanceof \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection) {
            $select = $result->getSelect();
            $select->joinLeft(
                ['shipper_order_join' => $this->resource->getTableName('shipperhq_order_detail_grid')],
                'entity_id' . '=shipper_order_join.' . 'order_id',
                []
            );
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
}
```

The other conflicting file from the Gift Registry module

`Orders.php`

```
<?php

namespace Mirasvit\Giftr\Block\Adminhtml\Registry\Edit\Tab;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface;

class Orders extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
implements TabInterface
{
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
 */
protected $collectionFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
 */
protected $registry;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context
 */
protected $context;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    $this->registry = $registry;
    $this->context = $context;
    parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
}

/**
 * @return void
 */
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setDefaultSort('created_at', 'desc');
    $this->setId('edit_tab_orders');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
}

/**
 * Prepare collection for grid
 *
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $registry = $this->registry->registry('current_registry');
    $orderIds = ($registry->hasOrders()) ? $registry->getOrderIds() : [0];
    $collection = null;

    $collection = $this->collectionFactory->getReport('sales_order_grid_data_source')
        ->addFieldToSelect(
            [
                'entity_id',
                'increment_id',
                'created_at',
                'grand_total',
                'billing_name',
                'shipping_name',
                'status'
            ]
        )
        ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in', $orderIds]);


    $this->setCollection($collection);
    parent::_prepareCollection();

    $this->prepareTotals(['grand_total' => 0]);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Prepare total row for grid.
 *
 * @param array $fields - fields to count with default values
 *
 * @return $this
 */
private function prepareTotals(array $fields = [])
{
    $totals = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
    foreach ($this->getCollection() as $item) {
        foreach ($fields as $field => $value) {
            $fields[$field] += $item->getData($field);
        }
    }

    $totals->setData($fields);

    $this->setCountTotals(true);
    $this->setTotals($totals);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Prepare grid columns
 *
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('increment_id', [
        'header' => __('Order #'),
        'index' => 'increment_id',
        'align' => 'center',
        'width' => '100px',
        'totals_label' => __('Total'),
    ]);

    $this->addColumn('order_created_at', [
        'header' => __('Purchased On'),
        'index' => 'created_at',
        'type' => 'datetime',
    ]);

    $this->addColumn('billing_name', [
        'header' => __('Bill to Name'),
        'index' => 'billing_name',
    ]);

    $this->addColumn('shipping_name', [
        'header' => __('Ship to Name'),
        'index' => 'shipping_name',
    ]);

    $this->addColumn('status', [
        'header' => __('Order Status'),
        'index' => 'status',
        'width' => '100px',
    ]);

    $this->addColumn('grand_total', [
        'header' => __('Order Total'),
        'index' => 'grand_total',
        'type' => 'currency',
        'currency' => 'order_currency_code',
    ]);

    $this->addColumn('action', [
        'header' => __('Action'),
        'align' => 'center',
        'filter' => false,
        'sortable' => false,
        'width' => '100px',
        'type' => 'action',
        'getter' => 'getId',
        'header_css_class' => 'a-center',
        'totals_label' => '',
        'actions' => [
            [
                'url' => ['base' => 'sales/order/view/'],
                'caption' => __('View'),
                'field' => 'order_id',
            ],
        ],
    ]);

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}

/**
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order|\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRowUrl($row)
{
    return $this->getUrl('sales/order/view', ['order_id' => $row->getId()]);
}

/**
 * Used for AJAX loading
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getGridUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', ['_current' => true, 'block_id' => $this->getId()]);
}

public function getTabLabel()
{
    return __('Orders');
}

public function getTabTitle()
{
    return $this->getTabLabel();
}

public function canShowTab()
{
    return true;
}

public function isHidden()
{
    return false;
}
}
```

Does anyone know a workaround so I can use my module alongside the third-party modules I have installed? In short, there are multiple modules trying to use the `entity_id` column from `sales_order_grid` table.

Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was resolved by both third-party module creators. Which both were simple solutions.

ShipperHQ - CollectionFactory.php

Replaced this:

```
$select->joinLeft(
            ['shipper_order_join' => $this->resource->getTableName('shipperhq_order_detail_grid')],
            'entity_id' . '=shipper_order_join.' . 'order_id',
            []
        );
```

With this:

```
$select->joinLeft(
            ['shipper_order_join' => $this->resource->getTableName('shipperhq_order_detail_grid')],
            'main_table.entity_id' . '=shipper_order_join.' . 'order_id',
            []
        );
```

Mirasvit - Gift Registry - Orders.php

Replaced this:

```
->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in', $orderIds]);
```

With this:

```
->addFieldToFilter('main_table.entity_id', ['in' => $orderIds]);
```

Now all is well! No conflicts!